# Why are my images not loading using Angular 1.6 and Webpack 4?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have an angular 1.6.9. project that I am building with Webpack 4.  I cannot get my images specified in my html to load.  Here is my setup.

I have a controller where I am loading the html with a basic require statement.

controller.js -

```
var config = function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/data/algorithm-input', {
        controller: 'algorithmInputController',
        template: require("./algorithm-input.html")
    });
};

module.exports = { config, controller };
```

My html:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="height:60px;padding-top:5px">
    <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="Brand" src="../../../img/brand_inverse.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

And finally my Webpack config:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
            attributes: true
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    }
]
```

Here is what is put into the dom:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="height:60px;padding-top:5px">
    <img alt="Brand" src="[object Module]">
</div>
```

I have tried `ng-src` and `src="${require('../../path')}"`. Neither worked.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix my issue.  It is a bit of a work around, but it does work.

In the controller I imported the image.

controller.js:

```
var logo = require('../../../img/brand_inverse.png').default

var controller = function ($scope) {
    $scope.logo = logo;
};

module.exports = { config, controller };
```

html:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="height:60px;padding-top:5px">
    <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="Brand" src="{{logo}}">
    </a>
</div>
```

I would love to see it imported straight into the html, but this is currently allowing me to ship.